# Get the top level parent id from a parent-child hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have hierarchy table. If a user queries a list of ids the output should be  only the top level id in the hierarchy for any of the supplied values. If the  parent id is available in the list it should be returned, otherwise the child id should be returned.

Below is the table and an example:

```
id   parentid
-------------
1  |  null
2  |  1
3  |  1
4  |  2
5  |  4
6  |  3
```

If I query 2,4,5,6 I need to get the output 2,6

The output should not return 4 (as parent 2 is already in the list) and should not return 5 as the top level hierarchy parent (5-->4-->2) is also available in the supplied list.

i.e if the supplied list contains values from the same hierarchy only the TOP hierarchy node should be returned for that particular hierarchy in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally clear on what you meant with why 5 would not be included in the output, but this would give you the results:

```
select id from mytable where id in (2,4,5,6) and parentid not in (2,4,5,6)
```

to go more than one level up in excluding values, you would have to join the table to itself.  Something like this:

```
select id from mytable join mytable parenttab on mytable.parentid = parenttab.id
 where mytable.id in (2,4,5,6) and
       mytable.parentid not in (2,4,5,6) and
       parenttab.parentid not in (2,4,5,6)
```

If you want to go to any level of hierarchy, you will need to use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).  Something like this:

```
WITH RecursiveParentList ( parentid )
AS
(
    SELECT parentid from Mytable 
    where id in (2,4,5,6)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ParentTable.id
      FROM Mytable AS ParentTable
      INNER JOIN RecursiveParentList AS ChildTable
                 ON ParentTable.id = ChildTable.parentid
)
SELECT MyTable.id
  FROM MyTable
       LEFT JOIN RecursiveParentList on MyTable.id = RecursiveParentList.id
 WHERE RecursiveParentList.id is null;
```

Note 1: you will need to debug this.  I am pulling it off the top of my head and will not test it.

Note 2: I would only use the IN clause for short little lists like this.  If your list of excluded items gets long or is pulled from another table, you will want to use yet another CTE to define that list as its own table and join your first query to it.

Comment: 5 is the hierarchy child of the 2  (2 -- > 4 --> 5)  as 2 is in the output 5 should not be there

Comment: Well, the sql I gave you would give you the results you wanted, but only because 5 is in the hierarchy 4 --> 5, and since 4 is in the list, its parent gets omitted. So that would only go one level up in the hierarchy.  If you want to be able to go deeper, you will have to join the table to itself.  How much deeper do you want to go?  Is just two levels enough?

Comment: it should be of any level hierarchy

Comment: Ok, you can use a recursive CTE, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Not sure about the query, because 5 never get filtered based on the above query can you please help to to understand.

Comment: CTE  looks infinte am missingsomething.Thx for you input let me check